# Pagination is not working on Primefaces dataTable with filter (first time only)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, pagination

I have an application (Websphere 8.5, Java EE6, PrimeFaces 5.3 on JSF 2+).

When I open this page in browser (tried Chrome and FF) and first try to navigate (there are 2 pages, 22 ranges in my example) - I get empty table (header says 16-22 out of 22 but the table is empty), and is still empty whenever I go back to first page - here how it looks like:
[image]

In case I filter table first - pagination works great.

I've seen similar behavior with another components - eg commandButton on other table, but this is minimal reproduction of the issue. If I remove the filtering - everything works fine.

I guess I have an error somewhere but can't find it.

Views contains following form:

```
    <h:form id="form">
<p:dataTable id="mainTable" value="#{rangeManagementBean.allRanges}"
            var="range1" filteredValue="#{rangeManagementBean.filteredRanges}"
            paginator="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            rows="15">

            <p:column headerText="Site" sortBy="#{range1.siteName}"
                filterBy="#{range1.siteName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{range1.siteName}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

while backing bean code is:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "rangeManagementBean")
public class RangeManagementBean {

private ArrayList<RangeDto> allRanges;
private ArrayList<RangeDto> filteredRanges;
@EJB
private RangeProvider rangeProvider;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    setAllRanges(new ArrayList<RangeDto>(rangeProvider.getAllRangesDto()));
    setFilteredRanges(new ArrayList<RangeDto>());
}

public ArrayList<RangeDto> getFilteredRanges() {
    return filteredRanges;
}

public void setFilteredRanges(ArrayList<RangeDto> filteredRanges) {
    this.filteredRanges = filteredRanges;
}

public ArrayList<RangeDto> getAllRanges() {
    return allRanges;
}

public void setAllRanges(ArrayList<RangeDto> allRanges) {
    this.allRanges = allRanges;
}
}
```

RangeDto is POJO with String getters/setters.

Comment: Not sure about your range filter. By `#{range1.start} - #{range1.end}` you mean the string concatenation like "str1 - str2", right ? Have you tried with a filter only using one attribute like `range1.start` ?

Comment: Yes, this works like concatenation. If I put both end and start in one tag it makes math on strings.

Comment: Yes, wanted to be sure of what you meant :) Then I don't see a clear error but I would try with a single attribute

Comment: Nice idea. Reduced it to "#{range1.start}", but the issue is still there.

Comment: Does your `RangeDto` implements `Serializable` ?

Comment: Yes, it does. I've mimimized example even more, see my edit

Comment: Oh right, then I think it might be due to the `filteredValue` list being empty at first. Try initalizing it with all values first ?

Comment: Trying this. BTW, its not my first similar looking page. I've done a couple before and it drives me crazy :)

Comment: This worked. I hope that this is a fix and not workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to the `filteredValue` list (i.e. `#{rangeManagementBean.filteredRanges}`) being empty at first:

```
setFilteredRanges(new ArrayList<RangeDto>());
```

You have to initalize it with all values:

```
setFilteredRanges(getAllRanges());
```

Comment: Is this still required for PF6.0? As I have tried it + added `System.out.println()` lines in setter, getter + where I initialized the list and it got always overwritten + set to `null` or empty.